# Unable to install SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Unable to install SQL Server 2012

Error

**SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error: 1: 2229 2: Q:\PCUSOURCE\1033_ENU_LP\x86\setup\x86\sqlncli.msi 3: Property 4: SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = 'ProductVersion' .**

Screenshot

[image]

**Error Details from Log**

```
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp: 
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp: Exception type: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:     Message: 
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:         1: 2229 2: Q:\PCUSOURCE\1033_ENU_LP\x86\setup\x86\sqlncli.msi 3: Property 4: SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property` = 'ProductVersion'
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:     HResult : 0x80004005
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:     Error : 1615
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:     Data: 
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:       WatsonData = 1615@2229
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:     Stack: 
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.MsiNativeMethodHelpers.GetDBProperty(ServiceContainer context, String pathToMsi, String propertyName)
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.MsiProvider.GetDBProperty(String absolutePackagePath, String propertyName)
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.MSIDetectionEngine.ReadPackagePropertyFromMsiMedia(ServiceContainer context, String installMediaPath, String mediaLanguageFolder, PackageAttribute definedPackage, String propertyName)
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.MsiExtension.MSIDetectionEngine.DeterminePackageInstalledState(PackageId pkg, PackageAttribute pkgAttrib)
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.PackageChainerExtension.SetPackageInstallStateAction.DetectPackageInstalledState(PackageAttribute packageData)
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.PackageChainerExtension.SetPackageInstallStateAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2014-01-16 04:21:28 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun, ServiceContainer context)
```

I had searched for this error on google but haven't found anything regarding. Please tell me how to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of the table name and stack trace, that is not an SQL query, but an MSI query.  I would bet that the MSI database `Q:\PCUSOURCE\1033_ENU_LP\x86\setup\x86\sqlncli.msi` is corrupt.  Try opening it with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or just replace it from known good installation media and try again.

If `Q:` is a mapped drive, there could have been a network issue during the read operation.  Copying local may rule out such issues.

For reference 0x80004005 translates to the incredibly helpful "The operation failed."

Comment: While opening it with Orca there was an error so I replaced it with a fresh copy from a another setup and setup in already on local drives, but still having the same error.

Comment: Does the copy you replaced it with open with Orca?

Comment: Yes, http://prntscr.com/2jrg7y

Comment: If it is really the same exact error, then there is some other MSI problem.  I would start fresh and try again.

Comment: Okay as you suggested now I'm going to download fresh copy and try again. Should I download from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/hh225126 again or go with http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29066